# Random Forest Classifier predicts lower proportion of positive cases compared to the actual

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, imbalanced-data

I am using scikit-learn Random Forest Classifier for a binary classification problem with imbalanced classes (negative class: 80%, positive class: 20%). When I apply the model on the same training dataset or test dataset the proportion of predicted positive class is significantly lower compared to the actual proportion in the data (16% vs 20%). I expect the proportion of predicted classes always to be close the the actual.

Below is an example of code:

```
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report

# Generate data 
X, Y = make_classification(n_samples=100000, 
                           n_features=30, 
                           n_redundant=0,  
                           n_classes=2, 
                           random_state=17, 
                           weights = [0.8, 0.2])

# Split into train and test 
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.5, random_state=7)

# Train random forest classifier
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 50,
                               random_state = 17,
                               criterion = 'entropy',
                               max_features = 'sqrt',
                               max_depth =  10
                              )

model.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Check average predicted score and proportion of predicted positive cases
# Train
y_pred_prob_train = model.predict_proba(x_train)
y_pred_class_train = model.predict(x_train)
print('Train: Average predicted score: {:.2%}'.format(np.mean(y_pred_prob_train[:,1])))
print('Train: Predicted % of positive cases: {:.2%}'.format(y_pred_class_train.sum()/len(y_pred_class_train)))

# Test
y_pred_prob_test = model.predict_proba(x_test)
y_pred_class_test = model.predict(x_test)
print('\nTest: Average predicted score: {:.2%}'.format(np.mean(y_pred_prob_test[:,1])))
print('Test: Predicted % of positive class: {:.2%}'.format(y_pred_class_test.sum()/len(y_pred_class_test)))
```

The model performance looks very similar on train and test datasets so it doesn't seem that the model would be overfitting.

```
# Get accuracy score and confusion matrix for train and test datasets
acc_train = model.score(x_train, y_train)
acc_test = model.score(x_test, y_test)
cm_train = confusion_matrix(y_train, y_pred_class_train, normalize = 'true')
cl_report_train = classification_report(y_train, y_pred_class_train)
cm_test = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_class_test, normalize = 'true')
cl_report_test = classification_report(y_test, y_pred_class_test)


# Print results
print('MODEL ACCURACY:\n \
    training data: {:.2%}\n \
    test data: {:.2%}'.format(acc_train, acc_test))

print('\nCONFUSION MATRIX (train data):\n {}'.format(cm_train.round(3)))
print('\nCLASSIFICATION REPORT (train data):\n {}'.format(cl_report_train))

print('\nCONFUSION MATRIX (test data):\n {}'.format(cm_test.round(3)))
print('\nCLASSIFICATION REPORT (test data):\n {}'.format(cl_report_test))
```

What is the reason the proportion of predicted positive cases is so different from the actual proportion? I expect that the two should always be relatively close using the default threshold of 0.5. Is there any parameter that I am missing when fitting the model?

Answer (score 0):

You're fitting a dataset on `100000` examples. It's actually **good** news that the model you trained is not getting 100% accuracy on the training data (or as you put it, the proportions of labels are different). It's good for two reasons:

1. It shows that the model is not [overly fitting](https://www.ibm.com/topics/overfitting) to the data you train it on. This fact will be crucial when you deploy the model in the real world, when it will be expected to do well on examples it has not really seen (i.e., generalize).
2. It indicates that the dataset/task is interesting/complicated. Otherwise, it could have been better to formulate a set of rules and use them instead of a statistical model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was wondering if there is a way to ensure that the predicted rate of positive cases is close to the actual? In a real life situation we normally would expect the event rate to remain pretty stable if the distributions of the underlying features don't change.